# Batch to delete all files that are not music files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I want to delete all files from my "music" folder that aren't .mp3, .mp4 or .m4a.

This is the folder structure:

```
H:/Music/Artist/Album/Files
```

There are pictures like Folder.jpg, playlist files, .txts and etc in those folders.

I'm running Windows 8.

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193282/delete-files-that-match-regex help?

and this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440692/windows-scripting-list-files-not-matching-a-pattern

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424380/delete-excluding-some-extensions

Comment: Please be more specific which step you are having trouble with. Is it the "find all the files" part or the "is it a music file?" part or is it the "delete the file" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set up an array with *do-not-delete-extensions* and compare all files with it:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "startfolder=H:/Music/Artist/Album/Files"
FOR %%a IN (
    .mp2
    .mp3
    .mp4
    .m4a
    .wav
    .flac
    .ac3
    .dts
    ) DO (
    SET "$%%a=1"
)
FOR /r "%startfolder%" %%a IN (*) DO IF NOT DEFINED $%%~xa ECHO DEL "%%~fa"
```

Please note: files without extension will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. MKDIR to create a temp sub-folder
2. MOVE all music files (*.mp?, *.m4a, *.wav, ...) to that folder.
3. DELete all remaining files
4. MOVE the music files back.
5. RMDIR the temp sub-folder.

Answer (score -1):

If this is a "one time task", use windows explorer (sort for "type"). This will be much faster (and safer) than writing and testing a batch for it.

Comment: Problem is I have over 100 artists subfolders and more subfolders in there.
But you have me an idea: I searched for "*.*" in the folder, sorted by type and deleted everything I didn't want.

Comment: -1. "Use Windows Explorer" is not a suitable answer to a programming question. This is at best a comment to the original question. It is not an answer.